# python requests post 500: Internal Server Error

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm creating a project with python requests where it will register an account for me with captcha-solving integration; I came across a problem with the error `500: Internal Server Error`.  Here is the code:

```
def captchastart():
    async_responses = asyncio.run(solve_captcha_async(nums))
    for your_dic in async_responses:
        for key in your_dic:
            return(your_dic['gRecaptchaResponse'])
    
data = captchastart()
headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'content-type': "application/json"
}
url = 'https://discord.com/api/v9/auth/register'
Payload = {
    'captcha_key': data,
    'consent': 'true',
    'date_of_birth': '1995-03-01',
    'email': 'random@gmail.com',
    'gift_code_sku_id': 'null',
    'invite': 'null',
    'password': 'PASSWORD',
    'promotional_email_opt_in': 'false',
    'username': 'username'
        
}
proxy = {
    'https': ""
}
y = json.dumps(Payload)
print("uploading to destination")
r = requests.post(url, json=y, headers=headers,proxies=proxy)
print(r.text)
```

##### What I did so far:

My problem started at the part where the `'captcha_key'` value needs to be fulfilled when its called/needed by the server. I tried just having the function there as the value, hoping it would have the same effect, but comes to another problem, where the data is not JSON serializable.

Then I tried using the python dumps method and it works! The data become JSON and the problem never occurs again, but when I sent my request to the destination, I received the `500: Internal Server Error` response.

I did a test where I send out the data without the function  `'captcha_key'` value and without the JSON dump method; it worked well just requiring the 'captcha_key' value.

I need help finding what caused the Error, and if what I did to the `'captcha_key'` value is right (basically I want it so when the server asks for a 'captcha_key' value the function will start doing the captcha-solving task! and return the captcha answer).

Anything is appreciated, I tried searching through StackOverflow but I just can't hit the right keyword since English is not my main language. If there is a post regarding this, I'm very sorry and will delete this post.

The code might look stupid but I did the best I could haha sorry guys. Thank you for your precious time!

Comment: You are missing a single quote in Payload - username

Comment: An 500 Internal Server Error response indicates the server receiving the request failed to process it—it is a problem on the server. Now, depending on what the server runs, the root cause can be from your code. There are some weird things in it, such as the function to get the CAPTCHA response: you have two loops and returns on the first iteration of each! I'd `print(data)` to see if its value makes sense.

Comment: @SWater I accidentally deleted it here haha

Comment: hi @brandizzi just did a test and 'data' the result does make sense to me, and everything should work fine, I believe that the server is running on javascript(JSON). and maybe can you let me know where the 2 loops are located? thank you previously